# Incorrect date/time is being captured in Data Extension through Lading Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, landing-page

I have a landing page form in which I am passing value to a date field in Data Extension. Whenever a form is filled I want date and time to be captured. The date is captured correctly but the time always stays to '12:00:00 AM'.

Below is my AMPScript:

```
    %%[
var @EmailAddress,@date 

        set @EmailAddress = QUERYPARAMETER('key'),
        set @date = Format(Now(), "MMMM d, yyyy")

       ]%%
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="FechaDeCaptura" value="%%=v(@date)=%%" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatDate function does remove the time aspects from the date. Since you have an input type below i believe that you have a form and a submit function which then takes this value and writes the Data to a DataExtension via UpdateData() or InsertData(). You just have to remove the formatDate function. If you not do this salesforce will default the time to 12:00:00AM (24h format = 00:00) which makes you see the result you have right now.

```
%%[
var @EmailAddress,@date

set @EmailAddress = QUERYPARAMETER('key')
set @date =  Now()

]%% 

<input type="hidden" name="FechaDeCaptura" value="%%=v(@date)=%%" />
```

On the form action page you will most likely have a function that takes the "FechaDeCaptura" parameter and uses this value inside one of the Data functions i mentioned on the top of this post.

When you would like to display the date like you formatted it somewhere you would just use:

```
%%=Format(@date, "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%
```

Comment: that worked well. Thanks a lot!